# How to fix: Google Cloud ML Engine submit job won't load

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

Here is the line I'm putting into terminal.

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training job4 --module-name trainer.run --staging-bucket gs://mltechnicalanalysis --package-path ./trainer --region us-east1
```

I've run the install.sh file in the gcloud SDK library and told it to update, I've made a new API key on Google Cloud's site, restarted my computer, and it still won't load anything.

if it helps, when I enter the above line, I hear my computer fire up the fan as if it's doing something computationally heavy

Here is a screenshot.
[image]

If anybody can help me figure out how to just submit a job, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Can you clarify what is happening. Does it just hang at the prompt?

Comment: Can you please provide some logs via  `gcloud ml-engine jobs stream-logs $JOB`. Any other logs like open Stackdriver agents logs or ml-engine UI (job section) screen shot is helpful. Please follow [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/troubleshooting) in case you want to know more about ML-engine logging access.

Comment: @rhaertel80 sorry for the long pause. It just hangs right at the screenshot and doesn't do anything.

Comment: @ShahinVNia it doesn't do anything so I can't even get a log. It's like it's not sending the job to google cloud.

Comment: 1- Can you please make sure that you have service account and enough permission to GCP? 2-  Have you enabled the ML API? 3- Can you run a simple ML job locally using the SDK?